# IP Address of my Salesforce Instance

Tags: integration, ip-whitelisting

We are building an integration with an external system which is behind firewall and they required whitelisting of IP addresses. We provided them with list provided by Salesforce (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1). But they say they can only whitelist 3 IP address as per their policy.

Is it possible for me to find out IP address of our Salesforce instance? Lets say we find it, is it guaranteed that in won't change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used the below in execute anonymous before - just out of interest mind. I've never checked but the ip is liable to change so I'm not sure how much help this will be in the long run.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://icanhazptr.com/');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http httpReq = new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
//http://icanhazip.com/ returns: 136.147.62.8
//http://icanhazptr.com/ returns: proxy-dfw.net.salesforce.com
```

Comment: Nice to see a way to get the IP address; I get your point that there is no guarantee if it will change or not.